# Update label from code behind

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am relatively new to ASP.NET/C#. I am trying to update a label tag in a update panel from the code behind while a long running task is being processed. Basically there are a few tables that are being loaded from a database. I want to update the label to inform the user when each table finishes loading. After a lot of searching I implemented it as follows,

```
<div id="LockPage" class="LockOff">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="LoadImg" AlternateText="Loading" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/loading2.gif" />
                    <asp:Label ID="WaitMsg" runat="server" Text="Please Wait...." />
                    <br />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind: Inside a method when a table finishes:

`WaitMsg.Text = WaitMsg.Text + "Table 1 Completed!";
            UpdatePanel.Update();`

The above code doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: This "method" you're talking about should be set as a trigger for the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Its actually the `RunWorkerCompleted` method when a background worker finishes running. I basically used multiple background workers to load the data from the tables. I want to update the label when each one of them complete.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/7126c23b-a03c-42b1-b97b-9f23ef84ff58/

Comment: Maybe this one is better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx You just need to find a way to register the ReportProgress - or something like that - as a trigger to the UpdatePanel. If there's no PostBack - Async or not - you won't see anything changing on the UpdatePanel. You can always go for Javascript in this case.

Comment: make it simple and update the level on simple button click event, just for testing to make sure whether aspx page is correct.

Comment: Using the background worker is not the issue here. I am using it successfully. What I am trying to achieve is to update a label on the user interface when the worker completes (thread execution finishes). The `RunWorkerCompleted` event is invoked when the `DoWork` event finishes. Now is there a way to register this event to update the label in the update panel?